# How to remove a directory without a name?

Tags: 12.04, directory, rm

`ls -l` output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 mnevile mnevile 4.0K Sep  9 15:45 ​​
drwxrwxr-x 18 mnevile mnevile 4.0K Jun 16 16:01 movies/
drwxrwxr-x 16 mnevile mnevile 4.0K Aug 19 10:52 music/
drwxrwxr-x 16 mnevile mnevile 4.0K Aug 19 10:52 tv/
```

How to remove a folder with no name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should know that this directory has a name but it's made of non-printable characters .

You can try this scenario:

Find out file inode:

```
ls -il
```

Output should be like this example :

```
261145 drwxr-xr-x 10 mnevile mnevile 4.0K Sep  9 15:45
```

Note: Here, 261145 is the inode number.

Then you can try:

```sh
find . -inum 261145 -exec rm -rfi \{\} +
```

Comment: Since it was a folder,  find . -inum 14573586 -exec rm -rf {} \; worked! And double thanks for mentioning its a directory name made of non-printable characters.

Answer (score -1):

looks like it is a directory with spaces . 
I would `cd` to that directory and use `./" " or ./\`

Comment: it's not a space.